# How would I mark an SSD Enclosure as an internal drive on Windows 11

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive, windows-11

I have an M2 SSD in an IcyBox external enclosure, however it is actually mounted inside the computer attached a motherboard USB C header.

I want Windows 11 to understand it is an internal drive (and not show it separately from 'My Computer' in the Explorer side bar)

I have googled but all the methods I have tried were designed for Windows 7/8 and do not work. Whats the correct way to do it for Windows 11?

Comment: Only way: Disassemble the enclosure and connect its disk internally. May not be possible.

Comment: it is by virtue of the fact that its connected over USB that makes it an external/removable device. if you want windows to see it as a permanently installed device, you will have to connect it to another bus, such as SATA, M.2, etc.  you may or may not be able to achieve that with this particular disk.

Comment: Ah that's a real shame that you can't tell it to treat a single motherboard header different :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few workarounds come to mind, not sure if they meet your requirements:

- Create a shared folder and mount it as a drive letter
- Mount a local directory as a drive letter

Also you could try to "attack" the controller directly:

- You could try to flip the Removable Media Bit (RMB) to fool Windows into thinking it's a fixed drive. There are a few tools out there but I don't know if it will work with your specific enclosure